# What is the Rainbowshield?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I just got attacked by someone and I looked at the troops the person used. One of those troops was an Image of an Rainbowshield.

What kind of 'Unit' is that rainbowshield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be the [Clan Castle](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Castle). The user deployed the troops that were inside, which were donated to them from another member of the clan. the Rainbow Shield is just the shield that's been selected for the clan.

If you check the User's Clan, as long as they aren't a hopper you'll notice that the Shield will match their clan's shield.